# Laravel pagination issue with blade template

Tags: php, laravel-4, pagination, laravel-blade

```
$contractDetails = Sample::where( 'name', 'LIKE', "%$searchText%" )
->orWhere( 'abbreviation', 'LIKE', "%$searchText%" )
->orWhere( 'description', 'LIKE', "%$searchText%" )
->orWhere( 'pp_summary', 'LIKE', "%$searchText%" )
->paginate($paginationNumber);
echo $contractDetails->links();
```

Here pagination is working fine,
but when i try to access the same in blade template ,

```
$this->layout->content =View::make('search.search',array('contractDetails'=>$contractDetails));
```

**template.blade.php**

```
{{ $contractDetails->links() }}
```

am getting a error : `ErrorException`

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::links()
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show more code on how you are returning to show the view?

Comment: @majidarif Can you please check the 2nd code snippet "$contractDetails" is the variable that contains details am passing the values to view by following way , `View::make('search.search',array('contractDetails'=>$contractDetails));` and it is a blade template

Comment: Yes but `$contractDetails` should have returned an instance of `Paginator`.

Comment: Yes am getting the same in controller , echo $contractDetails->links(); , but when i tried to access the same in view it return error, can you please check that

Comment: @majidarif   I tried to print the data in controller and seems fine, am getting the pagination links , but when i tried to execute in view am getting th error as undefined link function

Comment: Show whole controller method. You probably override the variable somewhere or use shared variable for your views.

Comment: @deczo thanks man, Your comment makes it possible , the problem is in looping same variable overrides.Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The problem is variable overridden, in looping same variable overridden cost the time.
Thanks for help me to identify.